# What does "unblockable" mean?

Tags: super-street-fighter-iv

What does the therm "unblockable" mean in the SSFIV series?

How does it work and is it really impossible to block or circumvent it?

Answer (score 5):

The term "unblockable" refers to an unblockable setup. This usually involves an untechable knockdown (e.g. sweep) and some form of timed jump in, similar to a safe jump.

In an "unblockable" the defending player will be hit if he presses forward or backward to block the attack. When you block backwards you get a hit by a cross up and when you block forwards the same attack does not cross up and hits you from the front instead.

Usually unblockables are character specific and do not work on the whole cast. Often the defending player can circumvent the unblockable by either focus attack dash canceling (FADC) out of it, but this is still somewhat risky.

Contrary to popular belief unblockables can actually be blocked, but it is extremely hard to do so. Basically you either leave the stick in neutral position or press forward and press backwards in the last frame possible before the attack hits. This means blocking an unblockable is as hard as an one frame link without plinking or double tapping 1/60 second.

This has to do with a bug / glitch in the game where if you block backwards the center coordinate of your character shifts slightly forward. Please watch [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XqpiyuwRstw) for further information.

**How to block and unblockable?**: Latif claims to have an easy way to block *most* unblockables. Basically you wiggle block  normal / block crossup once on wakeup (stick: blackwards and then forwards). Here is a [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=sQ7eYlkxqrw).

Comment: I suppose you can FADC out of it by doing some sort of cancel, but more common is just a focus to absorb the attack followed by a dash out. This is often vulnerable to option selects, however. Also worth noting are reversal specials with appropriate invulnerability, depending on the attack.